# Output array parameter in a C++ DLL function called from VB6

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, vb6

I need an array as an output parameter in a C++ function which is then called from VB6. I am using VS 2015 with C++ for the DLL project.

I couldn't find a way to create the array and return it in the C++ code (which would be the best solution), so I am trying to create a big enough array in the VB6 code and pass it as a parameter, then change it in the C++ code and use the result values in VB6 again. Below is an example with a byte array but my final function needs to be an array of structures, so solutions with string at the place of the byte array don't work.

C++ code (the call itself works):

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) void  __stdcall Test(
    char* data, int* len)
{
    *len = 3;
    data[0] = 1;
    data[1] = 2;
    data[2] = 3;
}
```

VB6 code: the code works, the length parameter is changed as expected but the data array does not change, it remains zeros:

```vb
Private Declare Sub Test Lib "MyDll.dll" (ByRef data() As Byte, length As Long)

Dim data(10) As Byte
Dim length As Long
Call Test(data, length)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an array of strings in VBA/Excel and send it to a C++ DLL so that it can be itterated through in the DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44637879/11683)

Comment: It explains all the `SAFEARRAY*` business that you would need to "create the array and return it in the C++ code (which would be the best solution)". Parameter types stay the same, the only difference is that you'd also be calling `SafeArrayCreate` on the C++ side.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644876/how-to-pass-array-to-vba-from-a-c-dll).

It  is to declare and call the function in VB6 like this:

```
Private Declare Sub Test Lib "MyDll.dll" (ByRef data As Byte, length As Long)

Dim data(10) As Byte
Dim length As Long
Call Test(data(LBound(data)), length)
```

Comment: Actually I did not mention this technique because it is generally not suited for arrays of user-defined types. It is okay for arrays of built-in types, and it may be okay for structures that do not contain strings, but for structures with strings it is not going to be okay because, seeing the `byref data as struct_type`, VB will convert just the first instance of the structure [to ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23980044/11683) and pass a pointer to that, which will break the C++ code that will try to use pointer math on that pointer.

Comment: To be safe, you need to declare `byval data as long`, pass `VarPtr(data(LBound(data))`, and handle wide strings on the C++ side.